# Inheritance of nested generics [object orientation]

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

### Idealized scenario

Let's imagine a scenario, with 2 classes like `A` and `B` where B extends A.
I also have a third generic class `C<T>` with a method `m(T t)`.

If I create a object `C<C<A>> container` and another object `C<B> obj = new C<>();` why can't I run `container.m(obj)`?

### Full code example

```
public class Test {
    class A {}
    class B extends A {}
    class C<T> {
        void m(T t) {}
    }
    void test() {
        C<C<A>> container = new C<>();
        C<B> obj = new C<>();

        container.m(obj);
    }
}
```

### Practical case

This Issue becomes apparent with nested lists where the `C<A>` in my simplified example would be a a `List<A>`.

Oracle highlights some [limitations of generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html), but I can't find anything describing this issue and how to deal with it.

Comment: Because `C<B>` is not a subclass of `C<A>`.  Consider a `List<Number>` and a `List<Integer>`:  The first List may contain Integers, Doubles, Floats, Shorts, etc.  The second list cannot be treated like a `List<Number>` because it is not allowed to contain anything other than Integer elements.

Comment: PECS. Producer Extends, Consumer Super. `C<C<? extends A>> container = new C<>();`

Comment: @VGR I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but shouldn't the `List<Integer>` lose the distinct properties of `Integer`  and behave like `List<Number>`. I get the base argument, but isn't this inconsistent with java's normal way of implicitly type conversion?

Comment: No.  `List<Integer>` is **not** a subclass of `List<Number>`.  It does not inherit anything from `List<Number>`.  It cannot be used in place of a `List<Number>`.

Comment: Related: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265)

Answer (score 0):

### The issue

As VGR pointed out: `C<B>` doesn't extend `C<A>`.

So `C<B>` other than `B` itself, doesn't have any properties of `C<A>`.

This becomes more clear, when looking at what `C<A>` and `C<B>` generate: `C<A>` acts like a

```java
class D {
    void m(A t) {}
}
```

while `C<B>` acts like a

```java
class E {
    void m(B t) {}
}
```

When looking at it in this unraveled fashion, it becomes apparent, that class `E` doesn't extend class `D`.

### The solution

As Elliott Frisch said, this can be avoided by changing `C<A>` to `C<? extends A>`.

#### Full working example:

```java
public class Test {
    class A {}
    class B extends A {}
    class C<T> {
        void m(T t) {}
    }
    void test() {
        C<C<? extends A>> container = new C<>();
        C<B> obj = new C<>();
        container.m(obj);
    }
}
```